# Problem float:right with Multi-column layout?

Tags: css

I want put content `li` in 2 column and want use of `float:right;` in `fieldset`, but this `float` creates problem in display columns is. how with use of `float:right`, this problem can be solved?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/w2XWu/

```
ol#hi{
    -o-column-count: 2;
    -icab-column-count: 2;
    -khtml-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 3;
    -o-column-rule: 1px solid black;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
    column-rule: 1px solid black;
}
fieldset {
    background-color: #EEF3F7;
    position: relative;
    float: right;           /*problem is this line*/
    direction: rtl;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    display:inline;
}


<fieldset>
    <legend>
    hi </legend>
    <div class="find_input mediumCell">
        <div class="column">
            <ol id="hi">
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>how</li>
                <li>what</li>
                <li>Normalized</li>
                <li>Mootools </li>
                <li>CSS</li>
                <li>attributes </li>
                <li>More </li>
                <li>Library</li>
                <li>Choose </li>
                <li>Please </li>
                <li>Framework</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the elements in a fieldset?

Comment: @Tim B James Because there are several different elements together.
Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: Wrap then in a `div` tag. `fieldset` is for containing form elements, e.g. inputs, selects, buttons, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by adding `width:100%;` (or whatever width you want the fieldset to be) to your fieldset style

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DyU9S/1/

**UPDATE**

Reason this is happening:

You've set the fieldset display to `inline`, so the fieldset will only grow to the width that you tell it to, or the smallest amount of space it can take up. If you want it to grow to 100% either make the display `block` or `inline-block`. Other than that pick a width that you want the fieldset to be and it will be that width.

Comment: Ok,in the [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w2XWu/3/) why not work `min-width: 350px;` for `fieldset` (`Hellodjjdhjhd jhdjhdjhjdjhdjh djhdjhdddd`) ?

Comment: It is working, you've set a minimum width of 350px and the fieldset has expanded to 350px, just like you asked! I've updated the answer above with some more info which should help

Comment: Fair enough, just set `width:100%` then and it will grow to the full width. If that doesn't work I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.